# Dispatcher inside a class

Tags: python, dispatcher

I have this block of code:

```
class InputLayer():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Test')

class Model():

    layer_type_map = {
        'input_layer': InputLayer
    }

    def __init__(self, architecture):

        for layer in architecture:

            layer_class = self.layer_type_map[list(layer.keys())[0]]
            layer_class()
```

My question is: in that penultimate line, why I need to put `self.`?

I am instantiating as:

```
layer0 = {'input_layer': {'input_shape': input_shape}}
layer1 = {'fc_layer': {'num_nodes' : 5}}
layer2 = {'output_layer': {'num_outputs' : 10}}

architecture = [layer0, layer1, layer2]

mynet = Model(architecture)
```

If I use the code correctly, the value of `layer_type_map[list(layer.keys())[0]]` is `InputLayer`, but `InputLayer` is not a method of the `Model` class. Why does this work?

I'm new regarding classes and objects, but I guess this is a way of handling things is a 'Dispatcher'. Am I right?

Comment: How are you instantiating `Model`? `InputLayer` is not a method as you say, but it is `callable` because of its `__init__` method. `callable(InputLayer)` returns `True`.

Comment: I am just doing `a = Model()`. I don't quite understand your answer, but are you saying that I can call the class `InputLayer` as a method because of the `__init__ ` method ? I didn't know classes could be methods, can you point me to some documentation on this? Thanks!

Comment: You can’t do ‘Model()’ since it is missing 1 required positional argument (architecture). It is the init method that makes the class callable. I’m curious where you were reading about this dispatcher pattern. It may help to make your question a bit more specific.

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited my question now. I just found a piece of code that was using that and discovered the name of this technique through another stack overflow question.

Comment: You need to put the `self.` before `layer_type_map` because it's a `class` attribute (that will be shared by all instance of the `class`). To reference them within a method of a class you can use either `self.` or the class name, i.e. `Model.`. The latter will also work _outside_ methods of the class if desired (but that might not be a good thing to do because it's a bit like using a global variable depending on exactly why you're doing it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: in that penultimate line, why I need to put self.?

Because `layer_type_map` is an attribute of `Model`, you need to refer to it whenever you want to access, by specify it with an instance of `Model`, by using `self`

> If I use the code correctly, the value of
>   layer_type_map[list(layer.keys())[0]] is InputLayer, but InputLayer is
>   not a method of the Model class. Why does this work?

`InputLayer` is not a method of `Model`, but it is set in

```
layer_type_map = {
    'input_layer': InputLayer
}
```

Since in the penultimate line, you've called `self.layer_type_map[list(layer.keys())[0]`, you get the `layer_type_map['input_layer']`'s value, which is `class InputLayer`. Then you instantiate it by calling `layer_class()`

That is why your code work :D I haven't tried it yet but that is my brief explanation. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `self` in your code because `layer_type_map` is a class variable. The rest of the code is just confusing you, I think. You can demonstrate the use of `self` in this context with a much simpler example:

```
class Foo:
    class_var = "a class variable"

    def method(self):
        print("accessing class_var via self works", self.class_var)
        print("so does accessing class_var via Foo", Foo.class_var)
        print("accessing class_var directly doesn't work", class_var) # raises an exception

instance = Foo()
instance.method()
```

The `self` in your code is being used to look up `self.layer_type_map`, which is a dictionary. The indexing that gets done to the dictionary (to eventually get `InputLayer`) has nothing to do with the variable lookup, which happens first. The `InputLayer` class was looked up (in the global namespace) when the class was defined, and a reference to it was put into the dictionary.